Can LLVM's ScalarEvolution (SCEV) be used for machine IR?
Scalar evolution (SCEV) is a powerful analysis pass in LLVM. I am considering the potential application of SCEV, and specifically SCEV-AA (Scalar Evolution Alias Analysis), within the context of machine IR, particularly post register allocation. My objective is to leverage SCEV-AA to enhance the instruction dependence analysis in my custom backend; however, I'm uncertain whether SCEV-AA (or simply SCEV) is applicable in this phase. I couldn't find an example in the existing backend. Could you, therefore, provide clarity on whether SCEV or SCEV-AA can indeed be applied at the machine IR level? Additionally, if such usage is feasible, would you be able to direct me to an example that demonstrates its application?
